# Not getting same results after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, rest, crud

I want to show the same results of my search after refreshing my page. For example, I am searching for one flyer by giving year, week, page, branch (2017,17,01, R) parameters through my get request. When I refresh my page, I come to the parameters which are in ngOnInIt.

I want to show the latest results according to my search parameters and not what is there in ngOnInIt(). Below is my component.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.showRaster === true) {
      this.jahr = this.year;
      this.woche = this.week;
      this.seite = this.page;
      this.filiale = this.branch;
      this.flyerhammService.getFlyer(this.branch, this.year, this.woche, this.seite)
        .then(
          flyers => {
            this.flyers = flyers;
            this.raster = this.flyers[0].Raster;
          }
        ).catch(
          error => console.log(error)
        );
    } else {
      // Below code is to get a flyer with current values of week and year and seite will always be 01

      this.jahr = (new Date()).getFullYear();
      this.currentWeek = String((this.currentWeekNumber()));
      if (this.currentWeek.length < 2) {
        this.woche = '0' + this.currentWeek;
      } else {
        this.woche = this.currentWeek;
      }
      this.seite = '01';
      this.filiale = 'H';
      this.flyerhammService.getFlyer(this.filiale, this.jahr, this.woche, this.seite)
        .then(
          flyers => {
            this.flyers = flyers;
            this.raster = this.flyers[0].Raster;
          }
        ).catch(
          error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
  }
```

I am trying to do it with afterViewInit but not able to get what I want. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and How can I show the same results even after I refresh a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your current search parameters (state) to browser's storage (SessionStorage or LocalStorage) in order to restore anything after a page refresh.

It is more to do with the fact that you are dealing with a single-page application rather than Angular specifically.

Comment: I thought of using local storage and found one article also but not understanding how to implement that in my code..still trying to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set and get data using local storage:
use the following when you set your field:

```
localStorage.setItem('jahr', this.jahr);
```

and then onInit:

```
let jahr = localStorage.getItem('jahr');
if (jahr) {
// get your data
}
```